# Array index out of bounds, couldnt find answer in other posts

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, indexing

I am creating an equipment system using blend shapes from Blender, but now that I added another blend shape it doesn't work. I get this error message:

> Array index (5) is out of bounds (size=5)

Here is the part of the script that doesn't work:

```
public void UnequipAll()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < currentEquipment.Length; i++)
    {
        Unequip(i);
    }
    EquipDefaultItems();
}

void SetEquipmentBlendShapes(Equipment item, int weight)
{
    foreach (EquipmentMeshRegion blendShape in item.coveredMeshRegions)
    {
        targetMesh.SetBlendShapeWeight((int)blendShape, weight);
    }
}
```

Secound script:

```
public class Equipment : Item
{

    public EquipmentSlot equipSlot;
    public SkinnedMeshRenderer mesh;
    public EquipmentMeshRegion[] coveredMeshRegions;

    public int armorModifier;
    public int damageModifier;

    public override void Use()
    {
        base.Use();
        EquipmentManager.instance.Equip(this);
        RemoveFromInventory();
    }

}

public enum EquipmentSlot { Head, Chest, Legs, Weapon, Feet, Shield, Hands }
public enum EquipmentMeshRegion { Legs, Arms, Feet, Head, Chest, Hands };
```

Comment: It would be. Size 5 means you have indices 0 through 4 to work with.

Comment: Read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/) `"Arrays are zero indexed: an array with n elements is indexed from 0 to n-1."`

Comment: Sorry i dont quite understand, but do you know how i can add one more index to this so i dont get the error. Sorry if im just stupid im not that good with coding and english is not my native language

Comment: The soluton is not "to add one more index" to your list, but to access the **correct** item. However it´s hard to guess why this error hapens without any idea on your data.

Comment: What line gives the error? Which array is size 5?

Comment: targetMesh.SetBlendShapeWeight gives the error. The hands is causing the error

Comment: @OlavAuslandOnstad I am not sure how that line could result in the error you are seeing.  Are you absolutely sure?

Comment: (int)blendShape corresponds to EquipmentMeshRegion.Hands. Is there something missing in targetMesh that you need for 'Hands'?

Comment: I am quite confused with this question. SetBlendShapeWeight is using a foreach. It shouldn't give you any error on that part. Can you trace the error? Also, what is a targetMesh? an object? an array?

Comment: targetMesh is a Object

Comment: Here is a picture of the error: https://imgur.com/a/X0ExbgY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SkinnedMeshRenderer.SetBlendShapeWeight.html), `SetBlendShapeWeight()` takes a `int index` and `float value` in that order.

Your code is casting a `EquipmentMeshRegion` to an `int` instead of passing the actual index.

Try replacing your `foreach` loop with a regular `for`:

```
for(int index = 0; index < item.coveredMeshRegions.Length; index++)
{
    targetMesh.SetBlendShapeWeight(index, weight);
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much i have been trying to figure this out all day. Sorry if i made this question more difficult than it should be, as said my english is not my native language.